# Select an integer type based on template integer parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to create a class template which takes an unsigned integer parameter and has a member `u_` whose type is the smallest unsigned integer type that will hold the integer parameter.

So:

```
template <uint64_t k>
class A {
  ??? u_;
};
```

For `A<0>`, `u_` should be of type `uint8_t`. Same for `A<255>`. For `A<256>`, `u_` should be of type `uint16_t`, etc.

How would you implement this?

Comment: If `k` is a `uint8_t`, then what does this mean?: `... = A<256,uint16_t>`. 256 is more than `uint8_t` can hold, so this doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Who upvoted this question?? It made zero sense until I spent a while deducing from the answers what the question was actually asking for.

Answer (score 15):

This piece of metaprogramming trickery achieves it:

```
template<unsigned int Y> struct typed
{
    typedef typename typed<(Y & (Y - 1)) == 0 ? Y / 2 : (Y & (Y - 1))>::type type;
};

template<> struct typed<0>
{
    typedef std::uint8_t type;
};

template<> struct typed<256>
{
    typedef std::uint16_t type;
};

template<> struct typed<65536>
{
    typedef std::uint32_t type;
};

/* ToDo - add more specialisations as necessary*/

template<unsigned k> class A
{
public:
    unsigned static const k_ = k; /*constexpr if your compiler supports it*/
    typename typed<k>::type u_;
};
```

The usage is exactly in the question.

The unspecialised template version takes the previous type. `typed<0>` blocks the static recursion. The other specialisations act as anchoring points for the appropriate types.

The compile-time evaluable `(Y & (Y - 1)) == 0 ? Y / 2 : (Y & (Y - 1))` reduces the number of instantiations by removing the rightmost bit of `Y` until a power of 2 is reached, and then divides by 2 subsequently to that. (Acknowledge @Jarod42).

Answer (score 13):

With C++11 you can use [std::conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::uint32_t K>
class A
{
public:
  decltype(K) k_ = K;

  typename std::conditional<K <= UINT8_MAX,
                            std::uint8_t,
                            typename std::conditional<K <= UINT16_MAX,
                            std::uint16_t,
                            std::uint32_t>::type>::type u_;
};

int main()
{
  A<100> small;
  A<1000> medium;
  A<100000> large;

  assert( (std::is_same<std::uint8_t, decltype(small.u_)>::value) );
  assert( (std::is_same<std::uint16_t, decltype(medium.u_)>::value) );
  assert( (std::is_same<std::uint32_t, decltype(large.u_)>::value) );
}
```

This assumes that:

- `uint8_t` in `template<uint8_t k, typename >` is just an oversight or, as pointed out in [Aaron McDaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146041/aaron-mcdaid)'s comment, the example doesn't work. I changed `uint8_t` to `uint32_t` (the example can be smoothly extended to `uint64_t`);
- `int k_ = k;` is a [in-class member initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization). For a constant definition you can use `enum {k_ = K};`
- `u_` in `typename u_;` is a data member. If it's a type definition you can easily change the example using a `typedef` or a [type-alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) (C++11).

If you cannot use C++11 there's [boost::conditional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/conditional.html) or you can write your own version:

```
template<bool, class T, class F>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };

template<class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { typedef F type; };
```

Answer (score 6):

If what we want is: given a `uint64_t` template parameter, give the smallest unsigned type that is capable of representing it, then what we really want is just a simple iteration at compile time.

```
namespace details {
    template <typename T>
    struct tag {
        using type = T;
    };

    // base case: just fail
    template <uint64_t V, typename... >
    struct min_unsigned_type;

    // recursive case: check using numeric_limits
    template <uint64_t V, typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct min_unsigned_type<V, T, Ts...>
    : std::conditional_t<(V <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max()),
                         tag<T>,
                         min_unsigned_type<V, Ts...>>
    { };
}
```

Then just an alias to wrap things together:

```
template <uint64_t V>
using min_unsigned_type = 
    typename details::min_unsigned_type<V, 
        uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t>::type;
```

This has the added advantage of being able to easily specify how far you want to go, or even being able to add larger unsigned types if that's something you find necessary.

And finally your class:

```
template <uint64_t V>
struct A {
    static constexpr uint64_t k_ = V;
    min_unsigned_type<V> u_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<uintmax_t Id>
struct A;

template<>
struct A<0>{
    enum {id = 0};
    using type = uint8_t;
};

template<>
struct A<255>{
    enum {id = 255};
    using type = uint8_t;
};

template<>
struct A<256>{
    enum {id = 256};
    using type = uint16_t;
};

int main(){
    typename A<255>::type a0 = 255; // uint8_t
    typename A<256>::type a1 = 256; // uint16_t
}
```

But I think you want to have a class so that every value under 256 will define `uint8_t`, every value under 65536 will define `uint16_t` etc. etc.

So just incase, this is how you would do that:

```
template<uintmax_t Value>
struct A{
    enum {value = Value};
    using type = std::conditional_t<
        (Value <= std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()), uint8_t,
            std::conditional_t<
                (Value <= std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()), uint16_t,
                    std::conditional_t<
                        (Value <= std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()), uint32_t
                            std::conditional_t<
                                (Value <= std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()), uint64_t, uintmax_t
                            >
                    >
            >
    >;
};
```

[And here's a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f04501c94e1b27)

Answer (score 0):

You can use using declarations for partially bound templates:

```
template<uint8_t k>
using A_uint8 = A<k, uint8_t>;

template<uint8_t k>
using A_uint16 = A<k, uint16_t>;
```

then:

```
A_uint8<7> hello; // -> A<7, uint8_t>;
A_uint16<256> hello; // -> A<256, uint16_t>;
```

Comment: How can `256` be the argument, when the type of `k` is `uint8_t`? The biggest allowable `k` is 255

Comment: As well as the problem pointed out by @AaronMcDaid, this does not fix the original issue of _automatically_ selecting a type, without that being done manually by the code calling the API. The main advantage that I see with automatic selection is that macros and constants can be used for `k`, and the type will be updated automatically with the macro or constant.

Answer (score -3):

Thanks very much. You guys rock! 
By the way, I'm using:

```
typedef typename std::conditional<k <= UINT8_MAX,
                        std::uint8_t,
                        typename std::conditional<k <= UINT16_MAX,
                        std::uint16_t,
                        typename std::conditional<k <= UINT32_MAX,
                        std::uint32_t,
                        std::uint64_t>::type>::type>::type TypeU;

std::pair<TypeU, std::shared_ptr<ProtoData>> min_;
std::pair<TypeU, std::shared_ptr<ProtoData>> max_;
```