# Are there standard integer types with sizes being template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, integer

Suppose I need to make a template with a member of exactly `N` bits in length, where `N` is the template parameter. I could of course define something like this

```
#include <cstdint>
template<int N>
struct sized_uint {};
template<> struct sized_uint<8> { typedef uint8_t type; };
template<> struct sized_uint<16> { typedef uint16_t type; };
template<> struct sized_uint<32> { typedef uint32_t type; };
template<> struct sized_uint<64> { typedef uint64_t type; };
```

and then use it in my template for e.g. a function:

```
template<int N> void myfunc(typename sized_uint<N>::type);
```

But are there any standard types like the above defined `sized_uint` in any version of C++?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334291/select-an-integer-type-based-on-template-integer-parameter/31334843#31334843, and my rather brilliant answer ;=). You could approach this similarly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no standard type like that. However, there is [boost::int_t](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/integer/integer.htm), which will do what you want if the boost dependency is acceptable for you. Note that the semantics are slightly different, in that `boost::int_t` will give you the smallest integral type with *at least* that many bits, rather than exactly that many.

Comment: With its 2016 date and its citation of Boost.Integer, [P0381R1] (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0381r1.html) supports the correctness of this answer.  Two of the things that I've wanted to use such a type for, though, are available in `<type_traits>`: [std::make_unsigned](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned), [std::underlying_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type).