# Convert HWND to Hex String in C++

Tags: c++, string, hex, hwnd

What is the best way to convert `HWND` to Hex String in C++, I mean also with a `"0x"` prefix?

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(L"Notepad", L"Untitled - Notepad");
MessageBox(nullptr, LPCWSTR(hWnd), L"Hello World!", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON1);
```

But I expect this to output `0x00000000` (assuming Notepad windows is not open) , but it always returns an empty string.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c), but I ended up with returning `0000000000000000`.

Anyone can help me on that conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not conversion. You just cast `hWnd` to a pointer to string. Almost always it will not point to a valid string, producing an undefined behavior when you try to print it as a string.

To do it properly, you should trait hWnd's bit's as integer and print it to some buffer as hex before showing in the message box:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>

//.....

std::wstringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << L"0x" << std::setw(16) << std::setfill(L'0') << 
    *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&hWnd) << std::endl;
MessageBox(nullptr, ss.str().c_str(), L"Hello World!",
    MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON1);
```

Notes:

1) `stringstream` is a C++-style `sprintf`. It's `str()` method returns `std::string`, so to get a C-style pointer you should call `c_str` on it.

2) I have no Windows to check what is HWND actually. So please check it's size and use appropriate integer type instead of `uint64_t`. It's important, as if you use a too wide type, you'll get garbage or even access violation. A better approach is to use an integer type template like one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541017/are-there-standard-integer-types-with-sizes-being-template-parameters).

3) Probably, you need `std::wstringstream` as you are using wide-char version of MessageBox.

4) Decoration. `ss << *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&hWnd)` just prints raw hex digits to `ss`, so to get the right format, you should fine-tune it, setting proper padding and filling character. For example, this will cause all integers to be printed as 16-digit numbers with leading zeros:

```
ss << std::setw(16) << std::setfill(L'0') ...
```

where `setw` and `setfill` functions are from `iomanip` header. Also, printing `0x` prefix is your job, not `stringstream`'s. Also take a look at `std::showbase`.

Comment: I still getting `0x0`, This seems conversion very hard in C++ those compared to AutoIt3. in it, it is really simple and only need to do is use `String(YourHWND)`. As it is also developed using C++, there should be something different to do this to return `0x00000000`. I can't find out what's it.

Comment: I will try again by changing `uint64_t` to another type..... :-}, And now I near to expected results when Notepad open. It outputs a six numbered hex, but I expect to output a eight numbered hex like `0x00000000`.

Comment: @Blueeyes789 I updated my answer. Also checked it on Windows, it works.

Comment: This may work, but now I can't compile it and C++ gives two `E0135` errors telling `namespace "std" has no member "setw"` and `namespace "std" has no member "setfill"`. I only included header files that you shown here.

Comment: No! Thanks, I forget it, I will include it right now.

Comment: `setw(8)` worked for me. :-) Then what can I do this to only return capital letters? any regular expression is needed to do this?

Comment: @Blueeyes789 If you have a problem and you want to solve it with regular expressions, then you have two problems :) It can be done much easier: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/uppercase

Comment: Thanks again for nice help! :-)

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowW(NULL, L"Untitled - Notepad");
std::wostringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << hwnd;
std::wstring strTitle = ss.str();
MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Caption message", strTitle.c_str(), MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a string representation of a hexadecimal number insert the `0x` literal followed by a handle into a stringstream:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(L"Notepad", L"Untitled - Notepad");
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "0x" << hWnd;
    std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

If you need to print out the result in a MessageBox use wide stringstream:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(L"Notepad", L"Untitled - Notepad");
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << "0x" << hWnd;
    MessageBox(NULL, wss.str().c_str(), L"Hello World!", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON1);
}
```

Comment: Above suggestion gives me `0x0000000000000000` when Notepad not open and `0x0000000000xxxxxx` when it's open, But I expect it to return `0x00000000` and `0x00xxxxxx`. :-)