# Convert a C++ integral type template parameter to a "longer" integral type

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have a templated function that accepts an integral type and performs a mathematical operation on two input parameters:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
R multiply( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) {
  R ans = static_cast<R>( lhs ) * static_cast<R>( rhs );
  return ans;
}
```

(For simplicity, assume that types T and R are always unsigned integral types, or that I perform a suitable check to make sure.)

In this contrived example, you can see I am doing a simple multiplication (just for illustration). The idea is to pass a type R that is twice-as-many-bits-wide as type T; this will allow the full product to fit in the return value:

```
uint64_t Product64 = multiply<uint32_t,uint64_t>( 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF );
uint16_t Product16 = multiply<uint8_t,uint16_t>( 0xFF, 0xFF );
```

I am wondering if there is *any* way to **dispense with the second template parameter**, and *automatically* compute a type that is [at least] twice-as-many-bits-wide as type T at *compile time*.

Note: Just using the largest available integral type (uint64_t) for R at all times is not a solution for me. Ideally, I want a compile-time-computed type that is *just large enough* to hold twice-as-many-bits as type T (e.g. when T = uint8_t, R = uint16_t).

It seems to me this should be possible with limits or type_traits or something similar, but so far I haven't thought of a solution. C++11 or later version is fine. I would prefer to avoid boost, but if that is the only way, I would be interested to see a boost-based solution too.

Comment: Related: [Are there standard integer types with sizes being template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31541017/673852)

Answer (score 5):

You can make your own template sized types and use them to define your return type, like follows:

```
#include <cstdint>
template<int N>
struct sized_uint {};
template<> struct sized_uint<8 > { using type=std::uint8_t; };
template<> struct sized_uint<16> { using type=std::uint16_t; };
template<> struct sized_uint<32> { using type=std::uint32_t; };
template<> struct sized_uint<64> { using type=std::uint64_t; };

#include <climits>
template<typename T>
auto multiply(T lhs, T rhs)
{
  using R=typename sized_uint<CHAR_BIT*sizeof(T)*2>::type;
  return static_cast<R>(static_cast<R>(lhs) * static_cast<R>(rhs));
}
```

[See it live.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d35b479b33abc168)

Comment: Wow thanks! I was working on something similar, but I didn't have the syntax quite right. Your example works perfectly.

Comment: Good answer. +1. What will happen if `uint64_t` is used as template argument for `multiply`?

Comment: @P.W it'll fail to compile, since `sized_uint<128>` has no member `type`

Comment: @Ruslan: Yeah. Just thought the OP should know that because he was using `uint64_t` as a parameter in the question.

Comment: @P.W uint64_t was not used as template parameter _T_, only as template parameter _R_, which was the _wide_ return type.

Comment: @Rusian which is a shame, because I believe x86_64 (and probably other platforms) have a 128-bit product for 64-bit multiply instruction.

Comment: @KevinH.Patterson if you really need it, you can make use of gcc's extension type `__uint128_t` available on x86_64 and a bunch of other 64-bit platforms. But beware of it being quite "raw": e.g. no native support in `iostream` etc..