# How can I have the compiler use the smallest type in a template 'const' argument without C++11 for use with a (constrained) 8-bit micro-controller?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that I use with my AVR library. It is a (quite basic) scheduler. My constraint is to have as much as possible determined during compile-time. Here's one (stripped-down) example:

```
template <const unsigned n>
void Foo::bar()
{
    static unsigned k = n;
    ...
}
```

The only thing I don't like is that I have to use a 2-byte unsigned integer when I could always use the smallest type that fits. Trouble is I can't (yet) use C++11 standard because the AVR compiler (the version of `avr-gcc` I'm using is 5.3.0) hasn't enabled that part of the standard. I guess I could write the same template function thrice with a type ranging from `uint8_t` to `uint32_t` but I don't like that either.

So my question is: [how] can I manage to have the compiler deduce the shortest type for the `const` argument of template function `repeat` ?

**EDITED**: The initial title of my question relied upon my misunderstanding of the `auto` keyword. However what I want to know still remains: to have the compiler select the shortest/fittest type for a `const` template argument. Why haven't I used the more appropriate title in the first place? I have no answer to that, unfortunately.

Comment: Try BOOST_AUTO macro.

Comment: Note two things: auto doesn't match the smallest type (not that big interest for you), the smallest type isn't always the fastest. Often uint8_t is slower than bigger types due to conversion.

Comment: `auto` uses the type of the integer literal, which is not necessarily the smallest fit. [All integer literals are integers unless suffixed with `L`, `u`, etc.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

Comment: You should be able to use this [header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), have a look at the `int_fastxx_t` types, which give you the fastest datatype on your platform whith at least xx bits.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334291/select-an-integer-type-based-on-template-integer-parameter) too, for a template for selecting the right type.

Comment: Your example doesn't match your description of it, there is no repeating. Also you share delay amongst identical `milliseconds` uses

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my knowledge about auto. However this doesn't change my requirement. Here I'm struggling with that form of declaration due to the constant being a template argument. And I want the smallest type essentially for code-size constraints.

Comment: @Caleth This function is called in a loop...

Comment: @klaus Your comment about `fast` types reminded me of seeing `_fastxx` types in AVR library. However they are simple typedef's in `/usr/avr/include/stdint.h` and no automatic width occur during compilation, i.e. a `uint_fast16_t` always resolves to an `unsigned`. I guess that's on purpose. I'll have to resort to other tricks, I suppose.

Comment: Yes they are just macros, but you don't need more, for selecting them properly you can use the SO-post that I linked

Comment: But review your design first, it seems flawed to me. For me it looks that what you basically want to do is: `int l_cnt  = 1; while(1) {if(l_cnt % 10 == 0)loop(); tick(); ++l_cnt}`

Comment: @klaus I indeed want to decrement a variable as it's the recommended performance-wise way for AVR. I could indeed use a modulo approach but then glitches are bound to happen when the counter overflows if the value is not a power of 2. Most of all I need some form of re-entrant code to proscribe locking other portions of the code that *must* be run all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll stick with 2-byte integers for now. I've checked the code for `<boost/integer.hpp>` *and I don't even understand a tenth of it*. Given the required amount of code to type to get there for only skimming off one little byte... not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

> The only thing I don't like is that I have to use a 2-byte unsigned integer when I could always use the smallest type that fits, which (if I got it right) is exactly what auto does

This is not at all what `auto` does. `auto` deduces a type declaration based on the type of the initialization expression. For example, `auto a = 1` declares an `int`, and `auto b = 1l` declares a long, despite the value 1 fitting within a `short`, or even `char` just fine. The deduction has nothing to do with being *smallest*.

To answer your question exactly (in case someone else needs it), there is `BOOST_AUTO` macro, that *"emulates the proposed auto keyword in C++"* in the words of its documentation. So, that's what you asked for, but I suspect that it's not what you want.

But, there is also a thing in Boost that is exactly what you seem to want: `<boost/integer.hpp>` header has a collection of templates that allow integer type selection based on maximum required representable value.

Comment: Just one question about `auto`: what if the micro-controller is an 8-bit unit? Would `auto` default to 2-byte integers all the time anyway? I must confess I'm a little confused by all this (excess coffee, lack of sleep if you ask).

Comment: @Nasha `auto` uses whatever type is deduced from the initialization expression. The architechture has no effect on that. If `int` is 2 bytes, then `int` is 2 bytes. If you initialize with `int`, then the type is deduced  to be `int`.

Comment: I understand `int` is an `int`, expressed that way, well, it is obvious, of course. The matter here is about integral constants passed with no type information passed as template arguments: what will the compiler chose with known optimization parameters. Bear in mind that `avr-gcc` is a modified version of gcc (to an extent I ignore for the most part of it, of course) so it could very be that the *compiled* result is an 8-bit integer variable whenever that fits, which is what (I thought) I understood about `auto`. I don't know if I'm making sense though.

Comment: @Nasha If integer literal is used without a suffix, it is an `int` (unless the value is too big, in which case it is a `long` or `long long` depending on which type can represent the value). It is only smaller if a suffix is used. Optimization parameters have no effect on that as far as the language is concerned, but I suppose that if it can prove that the value is going to be within a certain range, and that the variable is never accessed in a way that the size of the object could be observed, then I suppose that the optimizer may do whatever it wants, as described by the as-if rule

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :-) .

Comment: Stupid me... that's what [idmean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368074/how-can-i-have-the-compiler-use-the-smallest-type-in-a-template-const-argument/45369598#comment77696856_45368074) has written in his comment above... which I read at least twice /o\ . No more coding today.