# Deducing the type of an integer by its compiletime value

Tags: c++, c++20

Using  C++14, 17 or 20, I am passing two template parameters to a templated class: TSize and MaxSize.

TSize is the type of MaxSize. Obviously, both are known at compile time. TSize needs to be big enough to fit MaxSize.

```
template <typename TSize = uint8_t, TSize MaxSize = 15>
class Foo {};
```

How can I automatically deduce TSize by the value of MaxSize, so I have it automatically by just setting the value of MaxSize? i.e.:

```
if MaxSize<256 -> TSize=uint8_t
if MaxSize<65536 && MaxSize>255 -> TSize=uint16_t
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: only those two, or do you want to choose between more types?

Comment: the uint8_t and uint16_t are enough. In the end, it needs to be an unsigned integer type, since it's a size type.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334291/select-an-integer-type-based-on-template-integer-parameter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
template<uintmax_t n>
using FittingUIntT = std::conditional_t<
    n <= UINT8_MAX, uint8_t, std::conditional_t<
    n <= UINT16_MAX, uint16_t, std::conditional_t<
    n <= UINT32_MAX, uint32_t, uint64_t
>>>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/764f1f2657e7f2ab)

Comment: Thank you Nelfeal! Awesome!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to choose between two types based on a compiletime condition. And if you don't want to change `Foo` you'll need some indirection to pick the right type for `Foo` (maybe partial specialization would do as well):

```
#include<type_traits>

template <typename TSize = uint8_t, TSize MaxSize = 15>
class Foo {};

template <unsigned value>
using Size_t_impl = typename std::conditional<(value > 255),uint16_t,uint8_t>::type;

template <unsigned value>
using FooIndirect = Foo< Size_t_impl<value>,value>;
```

Comment: Thank you very much `idclev 463035818`!